# Approximate Identity: Dense Ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra without identity $1\notin A$.
Consider its minimal unitization $A\rtimes\mathbb{C}$.
Regard a dense twosided ideal $\overline{I}=A$.

Construct the element:
$$I\owns i\geq0:\quad\frac{i}{\varepsilon+i}\in I\quad(\varepsilon>0)$$

Why does it belong to the ideal?

For closed ideals this is clear:
$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon+i}\in A\rtimes \mathbb{C}\implies\frac{\sqrt{i}}{\varepsilon+i}\in A\implies\frac{i}{\varepsilon+i}\in I$$

But what about dense ideals?

Reference: Dixmier, C*-algebras, Proof to Proposition 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(i+ \epsilon)^{-1}$ lives in the unitization of $A$, which contains $I$ as an ideal. You don't need that $I$ is dense.

Comment: But a nonclosed ideal of an ideal of an algebra need not be an ideal of the algebra..?

Comment: To see that $I$ is an ideal in $A^+$ (the unitization) let $a + \lambda 1_{A^+} \in A^+$ where $a \in A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. Then for $i \in I$ you have $i(a+ \lambda 1_{A^+}) = ia + \lambda i  \in I$ since $ia \in I$ and $\lambda i \in I$.

Comment: Aaah true that ^^ Thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome :)